# Apache ECharts not showing visualMap pieces on time xAxis

Tags: javascript, echarts

I'm using Apache ECharts 5.2.2 and try to show some markAreas in the chart on a time axis.

Apache ECharts provide some useful examples to get into some specific options. [Area Pieces](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=area-pieces) is an example where you can set up your own `EChartsOption` with `markArea`.

I tried to adjust the example to my needs but I fail to get it running on time axis using `Date` object.

If you paste the following EChartsOption into the example, you get an idea.

```js
option = {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'time', // changed from 'category'
    boundaryGap: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value',
    boundaryGap: [0, '30%']
  },
  visualMap: {
    type: 'piecewise',
    show: false,
    dimension: 0,
    seriesIndex: 0,
    pieces: [
      {
        min: new Date('2019-10-11'), // old tag was gt
        max: new Date('2019-10-13'), // old tag was lt
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 180, 0.4)'
      },
      {
        min: new Date('2019-10-15'), // old tag was gt
        max: new Date('2019-10-17'), // old tag was lt
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 180, 0.4)'
      }
    ]
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      smooth: 0.6,
      symbol: 'none',
      lineStyle: {
        color: '#5470C6',
        width: 5
      },
      markLine: {
        symbol: ['none', 'none'],
        label: { show: true },
        data: [{ xAxis: new Date('2019-10-11') }, { xAxis: new Date('2019-10-13') }, { xAxis: new Date('2019-10-15') }, { xAxis: new Date('2019-10-17') }]
      },
      areaStyle: {},
      data: [
        // changed from string
        [new Date('2019-10-10'), 200],
        [new Date('2019-10-11'), 560],
        [new Date('2019-10-12'), 750],
        [new Date('2019-10-13'), 580],
        [new Date('2019-10-14'), 250],
        [new Date('2019-10-15'), 300],
        [new Date('2019-10-16'), 450],
        [new Date('2019-10-17'), 300],
        [new Date('2019-10-18'), 100]
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

`visualMap` defines `pieces` that has a begin tag `min` and an end tag `max` of the visualized area to highlight. Unfortunately, the area does not accept the beginning and ending of the defined `Date` object and highlights the whole chart.

What am I doing wrong to get it running on time axis? I found a [bug report](https://github.com/apache/echarts/releases/tag/5.2.1) that is fixed in version 5.2.1 for string time data. Even `string` is not working so I guess, I do something wrong here... Any clue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it.

The tags `min` and `max` in `pieces` needs a number to handle data in time axis correctly. So, giving the timestamp of `Date` object by calling method `getTime()` is enough.

```js
pieces: [
  {
    min: new Date('2019-10-11').getTime(),
    max: new Date('2019-10-13').getTime(),
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 180, 0.4)'
  },
  {
    min: new Date('2019-10-15').getTime(),
    max: new Date('2019-10-17').getTime(),
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 180, 0.4)'
  }
]
```

Maybe, someone else have the same problem. The documentation of Apache ECharts is sometimes not accurate enough.